# Could not create configuration. Provider name:salesforce

Tags: salesforce-connect

I have tried to connect sitecore 8.1 update 1 with salesforce as per document in https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Salesforce_Connect_Module.aspx and referring http://sitecorestudy.com/?p=167  . But frequently getting the error  shown below.

I have double checked the credentials and token values.

> ERROR Sitecore.Salesforce *** Could not create configuration. 
>   Provider name:salesforce Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Salesforce.SalesforceProvider.GetConfiguration(String providerName)

> Nested Exception
>
> Exception:
>   Sitecore.Salesforce.Client.Exceptions.SalesforceAuthException Message:
>   authentication failure Source: Sitecore.Salesforce.Client    at
>   Sitecore.Salesforce.Client.Security.AuthenticatorBase.Authenticate()
>   at Sitecore.Salesforce.Client.SalesforceClient.UpdateToken()    at
>   Sitecore.Salesforce.Client.SalesforceClient..ctor(HttpClient
>   httpClient, IAuthenticator authenticator)

Salesforce Account used is developer account and followed all steps in document. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the OAuth token request URL (TokenRequestUri) is hard-coded as https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token and if you are using a sandbox instance of Salesforce there are possibilities that the calls for the tokens are failing.

A similar issue is reported and answered by Vasiliy Fomichev on https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/3135